# how to render a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, render

I've built a helper which returns the string which I supposed to insert into HTML.
I'm using Haml, so `html.haml` file has this line:

```
= build_filetree 'small'
```

It rendered the result into this:

```
&lt;ul class=&quot;filetree&quot;&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;folder&quot;&gt;
folder&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;
span class=&quot;file&quot;&gt;nested_file1.rb&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;
spanclass=&quot;file&quot;&gt;nested_file2.rb&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;
li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;file&quot;&gt;file1.rb&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;
&lt;span class=&quot;file&quot;&gt;file2.rb&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

But I expected this:

```
<ul class="filetree">
  <li><span class="folder">folder</span></li>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="file">nested_file1.rb</span></li>
    <li><span class="file">nested_file2.rb</span></li>
  </ul>
  <li><span class="file">file1.rb</span></li>
  <li><span class="file">file2.rb</span></li>
</ul>
```

What is the problem and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use raw helper.
For example:

```
raw(“<ul class="filetree">...</ul>”)
```